# This batch script won't work, why?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following script and it will not work. I am trying to create 4 files, compare them all and keep the smallest and delete the remaining, larger 3 files. Here's what I have:

```
@echo off
dir /s /b /A-D folder\ > list.txt
for /r folder %%a in (*.*) do (
   dime.exe -A SCANTYPE=Q -A SCANL=7 "%%a" "%%a.q"
   dime.exe -A SCANTYPE=Q -A SCANL=7 -A SCANM=21 "%%a" "%%a.q21"
   make.exe -A SCANTYPE=X -A SCANL=7 "%%a" "%%a.x"
   make.exe -A SCANTYPE=X -A SCANL=7 -A SCANM=21 "%%a" "%%a.x21"
      for %%b in ("%%a.q") do for %%c in ("%%a.q21") do for %%d in ("%%a.x") do for %%e in ("%%a.x21") do (
         if %%~zb LEQ %%~zc (del "%%a.q21") else (del "%%a.q")
         if %%~zb LEQ %%~zd (del "%%a.x") else (del "%%a.q")
         if %%~zb LEQ %%~ze (del "%%a.x21") else (del "%%a.q")
   )
for /F "tokens=*" %%b in (list.txt) do del /Q "%%b"
del list.txt
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put the output files into a separate directory (outside the ``folder\`` tree)?

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    dir /s /b /A-D folder\ > list.txt
    for /r folder %%a in (*.*) do (
        dime.exe -A SCANTYPE=Q -A SCANL=7 "%%a" "%%a.q"
        dime.exe -A SCANTYPE=Q -A SCANL=7 -A SCANM=21 "%%a" "%%a.q21"
        make.exe -A SCANTYPE=X -A SCANL=7 "%%a" "%%a.x"
        make.exe -A SCANTYPE=X -A SCANL=7 -A SCANM=21 "%%a" "%%a.x21"
        for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%b in ('
            dir /a-d /b /os "%%a.q" "%%a.q21" "%%a.x" "%%a.x21"
        ') do del /q "%%b" >nul 2>nul 
    )

    for /F "delims=" %%b in (list.txt) do del /Q "%%b"
    del list.txt
```

There was a missing closing parenthesis in the code. The logic behind the file size check has been translated to `dir` command to get a size sorted list, skip the first one and delete the rest.

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong but I think you typo'd `>>`. Honestly do not understand the rest though haha. `dir /s /b /A-D folder\ >> list.txt`

Comment: I double checked and no, I did not put >>. The rest uses 2 programs to create 4 files. Then my attempt is to compare all four files and keep the smallest and delete the 3 larger files.

Comment: David: in a batch file, dir /b > file.txt creates file.txt. On my Windows 7 machine, that works. That is not the issue. All 4 files for each file in the folder get created, that is not the issue. The "if" portion is the problematic section.

Comment: `>` creates a new file or rewrites an existing file, `>>` creates a new file or appends to an existing file. Anyway, the issue is certainly not with redirection. Nice try but your answer doesn't solve the problem at all.